# MongoDB/Mongoose how to return a nested subdocument by _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nested-documents

MongoDB newbie here.

I have a 'client' document that looks like this:

```
{
  name: "myClient",
  products: [{
    name: "myProduct1",
    environments: [{
        name: "myEnvironment1",
        changeLogs: [
          { "some": "fields21" },
          { "some": "fields22" }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "myEnvironment2",
        changeLogs: [
          { "some": "fields11" },
          { "some": "fields12" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "myProduct2",
    environments: [{
        name: "myEnv1",
        changeLogs: [
          { "some": "fields1" },
          { "some": "fields2" }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "myEnv1",
        changeLogs: [
          { "some": "fields3" },
          { "some": "fields4" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

So a client has many `products`, which has many `environments`, which has many `changeLogs`. I am looking to return a list of `changeLogs` for a given environment, with only the `environment._id` to go on.

I can find the correct `client` document using just this `_id`:

```
db.clients.find({'products.environments._id': ObjectId("5a1bf4b410842200043d56ff")})
```

But this returns the entire `client` document. What I want is to return just the `changeLogs` array from the environment with `_id: ObjectId("5a1bf4b410842200043d56ff")`

Assuming I have the `_id` of the first `environment` of the first `product`, my desired output is the following:

```
[
  { "some": "fields21" },
  { "some": "fields22" }
]
```

What query would you recommend I use to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance for any help. The docs thus far have only been confusing, but I'm sure I'll get there in the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.clients.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$products.environments" 
  },
  {
    $match: { "products.environments._id": ObjectId("5a1bf4b410842200043fffff") }
  },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0, changeLogs: "$products.environments.changeLogs" }
  }
]).pretty()
```

Results in:

```
{
  "changeLogs": [
    { "some": "fields21" },
    { "some": "fields22" }
  ]
}
```

For those finding that code confusing I found it very useful to just add one aggregate method at a time, look at the results, and then add then next method to the pipeline. Once the pipeline was complete I also experimented with removing intermediary steps to see if I could get the same results with less piping.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the products array so that its environments can be fed as input to [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) after a [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on the `_id`.

*(lets assume the enviroment _id is 1)*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$products"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "products.environments._id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "logsArray": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$products.environments",
          as: "env",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$env._id",
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$logsArray"
  }
])
```

**O/P Should be like:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "logsArray": {
      "changeLogs": [
        {
          "some": "fields21"
        },
        {
          "some": "fields22"
        }
      ],
      "id": 1,
      "name": "myEnvironment1"
    }
  }
]
```

**Note:** notice the last stage `$unwind` of `logsArray` which I think is just pretty-fying the ouput. Otherwise without it also the resultant is acceptable (if you agree, can remove that).

Comment: I've upvoted because your explanation helped me to understand how to come to the right answer, thanks!
However your `$project` and following `$unwind` seem to leave me with no results.

Comment: @FelixFortis Not sure why you are ending up with no results. Do check the [plyaground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WO6aorRxa5b) where the query does indeed get required result from the sample set in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is just another way of doing the aggregation query. This gets the desired result.

Note I am using the "name" field of the "environments" from the sample document you had provided. The "name" can be substituted with "id" as needed.

```
var ENV = "myEnvironment1";

db.env.aggregate( [
  { $match: { 
  { $unwind: "$products" },
  { $unwind: "$products.environments" },
  { $match: { "products.environments.name": ENV} },
  { $project: { _id: 0, changeLogs: "$products.environments.changeLogs" } },
] )
```

*The result:*

```
{ "changeLogs" : [ { "some" : "fields21" }, { "some" : "fields22" } ] }
```

If the variable `ENV`'s value is changed, then the result will be accordingly; e.g.,: `ENV = "myEnv1";`

```
{ "changeLogs" : [ { "some" : "fields1" }, { "some" : "fields2" } ] }
{ "changeLogs" : [ { "some" : "fields3" }, { "some" : "fields4" } ] }
```

Comment: Your code looks a lot like the one I finally came up with, but is giving me syntax errors. I've upvoted, thanks!.